# Merging Value of one dictionary as key of another

Tags: dictionary, merge

I have 2 Dictionaries:

```
StatePops={'AL':4887871, 'AK':737438, 'AZ':7278717, 'AR':3013825}

StateNames={'AL':'Alabama', 'AK':'Alaska', 'AZ':'Arizona', 'AR':'Arkansas'}
```

I am trying to merge so the Value of StateNames is the Key for StatePops.

Ex.

```
{'Alabama': 4887871, 'Alaska': 737438, ...
```

I also have to display the name of states w/ population over 4million.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified in what programming language you want this problem to be solved.

Nonetheless, here is a solution in Python.

```
state_pops = {
    'AL': 4887871,
    'AK': 737438,
    'AZ':7278717,
    'AR':3013825
}

state_names = {
    'AL':'Alabama',
    'AK':'Alaska',
    'AZ':'Arizona',
    'AR':'Arkansas'
}

states = dict([([state_names[k],state_pops[k]]) for k in state_pops])
final = {k:v for k, v in states.items() if v > 4000000}
print(states)
print(final)
```

First, you can merge two dictionaries with the predefined **dict** python function in the states variable as such. Here, **k** is an iterator and it is used as index for state_names and state_pops.
Then, store the filtered dictionary in final where the **states.items()** is used to access the keys and values in states and type-cast it as a string with the **str** function.

There may be more simpler solutions but this is as far as I can optimize the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary Keys cannot be changed in Python. You need to either add the modified key-value pair to the dictionary and then delete the old key, or you can create a new dictionary. I'd opt for the second option, i.e., creating a new dictionary.

```
myDict = {}
for i in StatePops:
    myDict.update({StateNames[i] : StatePops[i]})
```

This outputs `myDict` as

```
{'Alabama': 4887871, 'Alaska': 737438, 'Arizona': 7278717, 'Arkansas': 3013825}
```